# Replacing runs of zero in a vector with a fraction of the previous value

Tags: r

I have a vector containing zero values:

```
x<-c(6,0,0,4,2,0,2,2,0,0,5)
```

How can I replace the zero values and the last non zero value using the number:

```
   last non zero value /(length of run of zero's + 1)
```

As an example first three elements should be replaced by 6/3 which is 2

So afterwards the x should looks like below:

```
x<-c(2,2,2,4,1,1,2,0.66,0.66,0.66,5)
```

Comment: `replace(x, x==0, 1)`  , your question needs more information. Did you try anything?

Comment: I have edited the post to make it more informative. I just want to equally distribute the preceding non zero value among the next zero values.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I see runs of a vector, the `rle` function jumps to mind. In this case, we compute the lengths of runs of 0's and non-0's:

```
(x.rle <- rle(x == 0))
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:7] 1 2 2 1 2 2 1
#   values : logi [1:7] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

From the run-length encoding of whether the vector equals 0, it is straightforward to determine the starts, ends, and lengths of each of the runs beginning with a number and including all the 0's:

```
(lens <- x.rle$lengths[x.rle$values]+1)
# [1] 3 2 3
(ends <- cumsum(x.rle$lengths)[x.rle$values])
# [1]  3  6 10
(starts <- ends-lens+1)
# [1] 1 5 8
```

Given this information, we can finally replace each run with the starting value divided by the length of the run:

```
x[rep(starts-1, lens) + sequence(lens)] <- rep(x[starts]/lens, lens)
x
#  [1] 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 4.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 2.0000000 0.6666667
#  [9] 0.6666667 0.6666667 5.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty simple one-liner with `ave` and using `cumsum` to do the grouping:

```
ave(x, cumsum(x > 0))
 [1] 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 4.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 2.0000000 
 [8] 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 5.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I am more familiar to work with data frame. Here is a solution using techniques manipulating the data frame to get the results.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Create example data frame
dt <- data_frame(x = c(6,0,0,4,2,0,2,2,0,0,5))

# Create row id
dt2 <- dt %>% rowid_to_column() 

# Process the data
dt3 <- dt2 %>%
  mutate(nonzero = ifelse(x == 0, 0, 1)) %>%
  mutate(Group1 = rleid(nonzero)) %>%
  mutate(Group2 = ifelse(Group1 %% 2 == 1, Group1 + 1, Group1)) %>%
  filter(!(nonzero == 1 & lead(nonzero) == 1)) %>%
  group_by(Group2) %>%
  mutate(x2 = first(x)/n()) %>%
  select(-x) %>%
  right_join(dt2, by = "rowid") %>%
  mutate(x3 = ifelse(!is.na(x2), x2, x))

# Assign the output back to x
x <- dt3$x3
x
[1] 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 4.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 2.0000000 0.6666667
[9] 0.6666667 0.6666667 5.0000000
```